# Add an extraQueryParameter login_hint in microsoft-adal-angular6 from angular component

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular6, adal, adal.js

Using the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6 i am logging in to azure AD.
In the app module i am using the extraQueryParamter as follows and its working.

```
MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({`
      tenant: "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/home',     
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      extraQueryParameter: 'login_hint=abc@xyz.com'
    }),
```

But i am trying out to find out how to pass this extraQueryParameter: login_hint=abc@xyz.com' from a component (in a login component page on button click, i am redirecting to a URL which is protected by authencationguard in route ).
Is there a was to do that. I cannot preset the login_hint in app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source code of that library i added one more function in the service file.

```
public login_userhint(loginid: string) {
    this.context.config.extraQueryParameter = 'login_hint=' + loginid;
    this.context.login();
  }
```

> in MsAdalAngular6Service.

that solved my problem.